# Sum and average value from CPT in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to echo the average of all ratings from a custom post type, but not getting there.

edit: total value isn't showing up, so I can't calculate the average

I was hoping someone could help me.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'ratings' );
$ratings = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = $ratings->post_count;
$total = 0;
$average = $total / $count;

while ( have_rows('ratings') ) : the_row(); 
    $total += intval( the_field('rating_num'));
endwhile;

echo $average;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Hi! Please elaborate what isn't working / What errors you are getting?

Comment: Hi! The total value isn't showing up, so I can't get the average

Comment: Does the field 'rating_nums' in the 'ratings' rows exist and have a value convertable to an integer?

Comment: Maybe stupid, but the row isn't existing. Do you know how I only get the sum of all values > the_field('rating_num')?

Comment: @Falch0n in Which fields you save the rating of post

Comment: @AnkurBhadania check my second answer, first question is solved but I'm not happy with the outcome (with decimals). Thanks for your effort, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Falch0n check my edit answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,`$average = $total / $count;` put after the `while` loop  because before the loop `$average` is `0` and `0/any number = 0`

You can used the [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) for get the "rating_num"

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'ratings' );
$ratings = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = $ratings->post_count;
$total = 0;
//$average = $total / $count;

while ( have_rows('ratings') ) : the_row(); 
    $total += intval( get_field('rating_num'));
endwhile;

$average = $total / $count;
echo $average;
wp_reset_query();
```

> EDIT

Used [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
echo round(3.453546);

//OUTPUT 3
```

Other option is

`number_format(3.453546, 0, '.', '');`

```
//OUTPUT 3
```

Comment: This code is not working for me, perhaps it's because of the row doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the value of the rating correct. Now I have this and the problem is mainly solved.

The only last problem is that the value ends with endless decimal. How could I round up the value through a whole number? So for example '3,453546' becomes '3'?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'ratings' );
$ratings = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = $ratings->post_count;
$total = 0;

if( $ratings->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $ratings->have_posts() ) : $ratings->the_post();
        $total += intval( get_field('rating_num'));
    endwhile; 
endif;

$average = $total / $count;
echo $average;
wp_reset_query();
```

Edit: Problem was solved by using

```
round( $average, 1 );
```